# Authentication support for the Spring Security plugin, authenticate using DB if ldap not available

Tags: spring, security, authentication, ldap, grails-plugin

I have a requirement in grails spring security.
When the user logs in to the application, check if ldap is available, then authenticate using ldap.

If ldap is not available, then authenticate using database.

Please let me know if it is possible.

My App does the following, 
it checks for the user in ldap, if the user is not available in ldap, then it checks database which is ok,  if ldap is not reachable for some reason, then it is failing with an error "unable to connect to ldap server"

but my requirment is, If ldap is not reachable, then authenticate with database.

Comment: that's weird. setup your ldap for high availability. Use two ldap machines that sync between each other and failover automatically.

Comment: If ldap is unavailable, it should go to database and authenticate with DB, it should not worry about ldap